# what is the difference of Monoidal transformation and blow up?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

can someone tell me what is the difference of Monoidal transformation and blow up?

Answer (score 2):

In the theory of surfaces, a *monoidal transformation* is the process of blowing up at a single point.  (See the discussion in Hartshorne, Ch. V.3.)